# In VB.net Datagridview, can't seem to loop an integer for rows correctly

Tags: datagridview

I have 2 datagridviews.   I'm trying to fill each value from a column in datagridview2 into every 6th row (col1) in datagridview3.    How do I increment for "x" by 1 step in DataGridView2(0, x).value? see below.

```
For index3 As Integer = 0 To 25 Step 6
                DataGridView3.Rows(index3).Cells("Info").Value =    DataGridView2.Rows(2).Cells(0).Value ' DataGridView2(0, 1).Value.ToString
Next
```

I tried putting a For Next Loop inside the For index3 Loop and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you have this in `DataGridView2`:

```
COLUMN0
-------
VALUE 1
VALUE 2
VALUE 3
VALUE 4
```

And you need this in `DataGridView3`:

```
INFO
-------
VALUE 1
...
...
...
...
...
VALUE 2
...
...
...
...
...
VALUE 3
...
...
...
...
...
VALUE4
```

Best way I can think of is like this:

```
For index As Integer = 0 To DataGridViewRow2.Rows.Count - 1
    DataGridView3.Rows(index * 6).Cells("Info").Value = DataGridView2.Rows(index).Cells(0).Value
Next
```

Just make sure `DataGridView3` has enough rows before this loop, or you'll get an exception.

Comment: Just had to change DataGridViewRow2.Rows.Count - 1 to DataGridView2.RowCount -1

Comment: You're welcome! If it solved your problem, please upvote and mark the answer